# How do i configure the app-routing.module in Angular 5 to load one or the other of two child routing modules, based on a condition?

Tags: angular, routes

I have the following application:

```
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── app-routing.module.ts
├── modules
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── components
│   │   ├── home.module.ts
│   │   └── home-routing.module.ts
│   └── user
│       ├── components
│       ├── services
│       │   └── auth-guard.service.ts
│       ├── user.module.ts
│       └── user-routing.module.ts
└── shared
    ├── components
    │   └── navbar
    │       ├── navbar.component.html
    │       ├── navbar.component.scss
    │       └── navbar.component.ts
    ├── services
    │   └── auth.service.ts
    └── shared.module.ts
```

The app-routing.module is just basic so far as this is the beginning of the application

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '**', redirectTo: "''", pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '' /*...*/ }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**My question is** how do i configure the application, so that the route `''` in app-routing.module points to the route `''` in home-routing.module based on a condition defined in auth.service, and otherwise to the route `''` defined in user-routing.module? The modules home and user each have their respective child routes.

The logic behind my question is that i wish to have two separate modules, one for the part of the app that users can access when not authenticated, and one for authenticated users. Once a user is authenticated, i want the default route to point to the related module and its routing module, based on the authentication logic defined in auth.service.

I realize that i can use `canActivate` to protect the user module, however i cannot find any resources that display how i can accomplish this conditional kind of routing logic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No can do. You should use canActivate and redirect to different routes based on auth state.